# IDFA app rejected, but later went into "Waiting for Review", adhoc behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know the fuss around IDFA & Limit Ad Tracking.

Since yesterday, I've been trying to update my app with ad-network SDKs, yesterday all day Apple kept sending me mails about Limit Ad Tracking not being respected in the code.

Later evening, I tried again, with a binary which was respecting Limit Ad Tracking(the same I had been trying all day), and the app went into "waiting for review" state!
By respecting Limit Ad Tracking, my understanding is ->

```
if( [[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled]) {
      NSString *idfa = [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
    }
```

After that I thought probably try again with the earlier ad-network sdk, which supposedly didn't have this behavior.
I tried with that, and the app again went into "Waiting for Review"!

Has anybody also faced such ad-hoc behavior?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apples Reviews process.

Comment: Its in-line with the reject rejection on Apple due to ad-networks library, so I think its quite on the topic!

Comment: Well Stackoverflow is meant for programming question, not Apple rejection questions. Please see the [appstore-approval](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/appstore-approval/info) and this post on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175701/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic-for-stack-over)

Comment: Sure I understand that :)
The programming part of the question was mentioned in the description itself!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Apple had made this as a brief change, which got ended late evening yesterday BST hours :)
Seems like all apps are going through correctly now, closing this issue!